Magento2.4.6: How to redirect a custom cms page to home page?
I want to redirect a custom cms page to home page
For example

https://magento246.com/custom-cms-page

to

https://magento246.com/


Just need to add URL Rewrite

Requested URL : custom-cms-page
Targeted  URL : https://magento246.com/
URL Rewrite   : Permanent



Here is code for redirect from custom cms page to Homepage
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View">
        <plugin name="yourmodule_view_page_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ViewPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>

app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/ViewPlugin.php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class ViewPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var ResultFactory
     */
    private $resultFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param ResultFactory $resultFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * Plugin method to intercept execute() method of Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View
     *
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View $subject
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|null
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View $subject,
        callable $proceed
    ) {
        $pageId = $this->request->getParam('page_id') ?? $this->request->getParam('id');
        
        $customPageId = 21 ;// Your Custom Page Id 

        // Example: Redirect to homepage if page ID is 21
        if ($pageId == $customPageId) {

            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('')); // Redirect to homepage
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}


Please accept this as solution

@Afzal Arshad
Hey,
you need to add below code in htaccess file
Redirect 302 /custom-cms-page https://magento246.com/
Thank You!

A simple solution would be adding a URL rewrite from the Magento Admin Panel.
To do so:

Login to Magento Admin Panel and go to Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites
Remove rewrite for request path = custom-cms-page if already exists
Add a custom URL rewrite with the following details:



Create URL Rewrite: Custom
Request Path: custom-cms-page
Target Path: /
Redirect Type: Permanent (301)


and Save the URL Rewrite.
Flush Magento Cache and check front end of the website.

window.location.href = "https://magento246.com/"
There are multiple ways. One way is using Javascript code to do redirect. You can add this script in admin cms page.
